# split the string in dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data-frame and one of its columns are a string which separated with dash. I want to get the part before the dash. Could you help me with that?

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
df['b'] = ['C-C02','R-C05','R-C01','C-C06', 'RC-C06']
```

The desire output is:
[image]

Comment: shouldn't row 4 have RC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to remove the `-` and all characters after it:

```py
df['b'] = df['b'].str.replace(r'-.*$', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
   a   b
0  1   C
1  2   R
2  3   R
3  4   C
4  5  RC
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to split each string on the '-' character and keep the part before it:

```
df['c'] = [s.split('-')[0] for s in df['b']]
```